# Want to show Welcome Page to new user and Home Screen to Logged in users in flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I have this Flutter App which shows some data to logged-in users but every time even a logged-in user open the app will open to welcome screen I want the welcome screen to open only when a user logs out or haven't signed in, to begin with.

This is the main.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:masterpass/Screens/Welcome/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:masterpass/components/constants.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MasterPass',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

code on github: [MasterPass](https://github.com/pranjalchaplot/masterpass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data == null) { //if user isn't signed in
        return LoginScreen();
      }
      return HomeSite(); //if user is signed in
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if user is logged using `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null` and use that logic to set the home page.
for example:

```
home: (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null)
          ? HomePageWhenLoggedIn()
          : WelcomeScreen(),
```